# Laziness with RxJava defer

Tags: rx-java

I am going through a book which tells how to intorduce RxJava in legacy blocking code.

It basically does this:

```
Observalbe.defer(() -> {return Observable.from(someBlockingMethodTofetchDBRecords(....))});
```

It says that defer would introduce laziness in the program. But isn't Observable by default lazy. Observable.from should return an observable and it wont do anything until we subscribe to it. So why do we need defer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `someBlockingMethodTofetchDBRecords` is not lazy and you hand its result to an `Observable` after.

Yes, `Observable`s are lazy by default thus they don't perform their subscription action until there is an `Observer` subscribing. However, `from`'s subscription action is to iterate over an **existing** sequence and emit its values. That sequence was handed, and thus created, outside of `Observable`.

Therefore, if you need to have the sequence itself to be created only when there is an `Observer` for it, its creation has to be part of the subscription action, for which `defer` is an operator to make that happen.

Comment: No. `from` iterates the sequence only if there is an `Observer`. Without an `Observer`, it makes no sense to run through the entire list just for the sake of it.